# How can I replace WHERE IN choices in WHERE clause to reduce execution time of the request?

Tags: mysql, query-optimization, unidac

I am using DBF database in a C++ project written on RAD Studio 10.2 Tokyo. To make request on this database, I am using UniDac Devart component (that is a little bit limited compared to MySQL itself). The problem I have is when using WHERE IN condition in the request, the request makes too much time to be execute (more than one hour sometimes).

This is the request I have :

```
SELECT accountrp, SUM(amounteur) AS montant FROM %s 
WHERE doctype='1' AND period<>'00' AND
matchno IN(SELECT matchno FROM %s GROUP BY matchno HAVING SUM(amounteur)<>0)
GROUP BY accountrp
```

accountrp, doctype, period are character and amounteur is numeric.

The problem is around the line matchno IN. I would like to optimize the request without using IN. I saw on Internet that WHERE IN condition can be replaced by INNER JOIN junctions but I Don't know if it is the solution and how to do this.

Can you help me, please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A first suggestion
you could change the IN clause in a INNER JOIN
this should be more efficent for performance

```
SELECT accountrp, 
    SUM(amounteur) AS montant 
FROM %s  as s 
INNER JOIN  ( 
  SELECT matchno 
  FROM %s 
  GROUP BY matchno 
  HAVING SUM(amounteur)<>0
) t on t.matchno = s.matchno
WHERE doctype='1' AND period<>'00' AND
GROUP BY accountrp
```

this because a In clause is equivalent  to a set of OR condition and the query is performed  each time for each OR  .. a inner join instead  is just a join between tow table and is performed  just one time

Comment: It seems to be very fast ! INNER JOIN and JOIN are the same think ?

Comment: yes inner join and join are the same ..but is more explici  and easy to read

Comment: @development  all the test you need ..but  the difference between a IN clause and a JOIN don't change  .. youd conld check that the difference in performance between the two method ins base on the numbedr of the lement in result  ...more elements more differnce in time ..and over a certain number of element the In clasue raise an error because there is a limit in the number of elements manage by IN clause

Comment: @scaisEdge In MySQL 5.6 and later, the subquery should only be executed once, and result stored in a temporary table.  What makes your query faster is probably that this temporary table will be first table in join.  This way, instead of reading all rows of table s, only the rows with relevant matchno will be read.

Comment: @oysteing   . you can try changing the order of nested  subquery and yuo can see that   a inner joion on subselect is always faster than a IN clause on the same subquery ..  this for simple  concept   ..each   result value  of a IN clause implies  a scan for this value in related  table  ..  (as an OR clause)  ..  for a JOIN the result set of the query  is itself a table  and the relazione between these values is scanned  just one time ..   The position of the table in the query is managed by query optimized  and can be influence  but in a complex  way not ever convenient

Comment: @scaisEdge Please read about subquery materialization. (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/subquery-materialization.html) It is basically executed as an inner join, but join order is unfortunately fixed.

Comment: @oysteing  . for what i know the INNER JOIN the materialization since  .. 5.6  at least  ..

Answer (score 0):

You can try with below

```
SELECT s.accountrp, SUM(s.amounteur) AS montant FROM %s s
  join 
   (SELECT matchno FROM %s GROUP BY matchno HAVING SUM(amounteur)<>0) t
  on s.matchno =t.matchno
WHERE s.doctype='1' AND s.period<>'00'
GROUP BY s.accountrp
```